# If ten queries are executed concurrently, is there only one copy of this data in memory or only one copy?

Tags: database, time-series, cnosdb

In the process of cnosdb query implementation, if ten queries are executed concurrently, is there only one copy of this data in memory or only one copy?
the fellow example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE air (visibility DOUBLE,temperature DOUBLE,presssure DOUBLE,TAGS(station));

INSERT INTO air (TIME, station, visibility, temperature, presssure) VALUES (1667456411000000000, 'XiaoMaiDao1', 56, 69, 411);
INSERT INTO air (TIME, station, visibility, temperature, presssure) VALUES (1667456411000000000, 'XiaoMaiDao2', 56, 69, 411);
INSERT INTO air (TIME, station, visibility, temperature, presssure) VALUES (1667456411000000000, 'XiaoMaiDao3', 56, 69, 411);
INSERT INTO air (TIME, station, visibility, temperature, presssure) VALUES (1667456411000000000, 'XiaoMaiDao4', 56, 69, 411);
INSERT INTO air (TIME, station, visibility, temperature, presssure) VALUES (1667456711000000000, 'XiaoMaiDao1', 56, 69, 711);
INSERT INTO air (TIME, station, visibility, temperature, presssure) VALUES (1667456711000000000, 'XiaoMaiDao2', 56, 69, 711);
INSERT INTO air (TIME, station, visibility, temperature, presssure) VALUES (1667456711000000000, 'XiaoMaiDao3', 56, 69, 711);
INSERT INTO air (TIME, station, visibility, temperature, presssure) VALUES (1667456711000000000, 'XiaoMaiDao4', 56, 69, 711);
```

Next, we execute ten of the following query statements at the same time

```sql
select * from air;
```

I recently looked at the part of the memcache code. I am a beginner in rust. Each field should be copied to the stream. I don’t know if I misunderstood this part.